# Add levels missing in one group to summary table using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

When summarizing data, some groups may have observations not present in another group. In the example below, group 2 has no males. How can I in a tidy way, insert these observations in a summary table?

data example:

```
a <- data.frame(gender=factor(c("m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f")), group=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2))
  gender group
1      m     1
2      m     1
3      m     1
4      f     1
5      f     1
6      f     2
7      f     2
```

data summary:

```
a %>% group_by(gender, group) %>% summarise(n=n())

  gender group     n
  <fct>  <dbl> <int>
1 f          1     2
2 f          2     2
3 m          1     3
```

Desired output:

```
  gender group     n
  <fct>  <dbl> <int>
1 f          1     2
2 f          2     2
3 m          1     3
4 m          2     0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end, we can use `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
a %>%
    group_by(gender, group) %>%
    summarise(n=n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    complete(gender, group, fill = list(n = 0))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  gender group     n
#  <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 f          1     2
#2 f          2     2
#3 m          1     3
#4 m          2     0
```

---

Or an option is also to reshape to wide and then back to long format

```
a %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = group,
         values_fn = length, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -gender, names_to = 'group', values_to = 'n')
```

---

It is more easier in `base R`

```
as.data.frame(table(a))
```

Comment: These are great options. I would also add that *if* `group` were a factor you could use the `.drop` argument to `group_by`: `a %>% mutate(group = factor(group)) %>% group_by(gender, group, .drop = F) %>% tally()`